# Average Speed using variables

Tags: calculus

A cyclist travels $m$ km at $v$ km/h and $n$ km at $u$ km/h. What is the average speed of the cyclist?

Is there a formula for calculating average speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average speed = Total distance / Total Time

Total distance  $=m+n$ KM

Total Time $=\dfrac mv+\dfrac nu$ KM/h